# How change the default login path for asp.netcore 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

The app is using Azure AD B2C for authentication

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                   .AddAzureADB2C(options => { 
                       Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                   });
```

by default when a page has the  `[Authorize()]` Attribute it redirects to the Azure AD B2C login page if user is not authenticated.

Instead I want the redirect to go back the application home page.  What is the way to accomplish that?

**EDIT**
Attribute created after answer provided.  This solved my problem.

public class AuthorizeRedirectAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
public AuthorizeRedirectAttribute()
{
}

```
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToPageResult("Landing");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write the redirect in either a custom exception handling middleware or in authentication filter.

Comment: I added attribute class to original post